# Azure Datafactory trigger based on parameter

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have an Azure Data Factory pipeline set for many colours (blue, green, yellow). We want to trigger the pipeline for a particular colour(eg: blue) based on certain conditions.

eg: Pipeline need to execute

- 3rd of the month with blue as parameter.
- 15th of the month with red as parameter.

How to achieve that?

Comment: hey @bludcloud , did this answer your query?
If yes, can you please mark it as answer as it might help the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than creating parameters in the ADF, it would be better if you create a variable.
use Set Variable activity to set it to corresponding color based on condition that if day=3 then blue ....
And use that variable in remaining activities.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Nandan. Just for some addition, it seems you have many colors. You can use this expression `@string(dayOfMonth(utcnow()))` in Switch activity.
[image]